# UTF-8 to UTF-32 on iterators using the STL

Tags: c++, utf-8, iterator, c++14

I have a char iterator - an `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` wrapped in a couple of adaptors - yielding UTF-8 bytes. I want to read a single UTF-32 character (a `char32_t`) from it. Can I do so using the STL? How?

There's `std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>`, but that apparently only works on `char*`, not arbitrary iterators.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

// in the real code some boost adaptors etc. are involved
// but the important point is: we're dealing with a char iterator.
typedef std::istreambuf_iterator< char > iterator;

char32_t read_code_point( iterator& it, const iterator& end )
{
    // how do I do this conversion?
    // codecvt_utf8<char32_t>::in() only works on char*
    return U'\0';
}

int main()
{
    // actual code uses std::istream so it works on strings, files etc.
    // but that's irrelevant for the question
    std::stringstream stream( u8"\u00FF" );
    iterator it( stream );
    iterator end;
    char32_t c = read_code_point( it, end );
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ( c == U'\u00FF' ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am aware that Boost.Regex has an iterator for this, but I'd like to avoid boost libraries that are not header-only and this feels like something the STL should be capable of.

Comment: Don't use the [tag:stl] tag unless you really mean the STL, i.e. the library from the 1990s from which large parts of the C++ Standard Library originated

Comment: @JonathanWakely Common use, the tag wiki, the tag short form, and utility of the term (who, really, talks about the original STL anymore?) sort of disagree with you there.  I mean, being pedantic is fun, but SO is more than about fun.

Comment: @Yakk, no, the tag wiki says it is incorrect to refer to the entire C++ Standard Library as the STL. In any case `std::codecvt_utf8` is part of the Locales clause, which nicely demonstrates my point because `std::locale` is not a template, and was never part of "the STL". The fact that noone talks about the STL any more is good reason to avoid using the tag, **not** to use it to mean something different. Important parts of the Standard Library are **not** templates (`std::thread`, anyone?) so it's just wrong. The [tag:c++] tag is perfectly adequate for questions about the C++ Standard Library!

Comment: @Yakk, and the tag short form contradicts you: "large parts of the STL were adopted into the Standard Library, and **these parts** in the Standard Library are also sometimes referred to collectively as ... " (emphasis mine) locales were never one of those parts, and `codecvt_utf8` was new in C++11 and definitely not one of those parts! So wrong on all counts ;-)

Comment: I disagreed with what you said: "Don't use the stl tag unless you really mean the STL, i.e. the library from the 1990s from which large parts of the C++ Standard Library originated".  That claim disagrees with the tag wiki, the tag short form, and utility of the term.  So no, the short form doesn't contradict me.  I agree, removing it from this question is reasonable; I did not revert your edit, just disagreed with your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do this directly with `codecvt_utf8` or any other standard library components. To use `codecvt_utf8` you'd need to copy bytes from the iterator stream into a buffer and convert the buffer.

Something like this should work:

```
char32_t read_code_point( iterator& it, const iterator& end )
{
  char32_t result;
  char32_t* resend = &result + 1;
  char32_t* resnext = &result;
  char buf[7];  // room for 3-byte UTF-8 BOM and a 4-byte UTF-8 character
  char* bufpos = buf;
  const char* const bufend = std::end(buf);
  std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t> cvt;
  while (bufpos != bufend && it != end)
  {
    *bufpos++ = *it++;
    std::mbstate_t st{};
    const char* be = bufpos;
    const char* bn = buf;
    auto conv = cvt.in(st, buf, be, bn, &result, resend, resnext);
    if (conv == std::codecvt_base::error)
      throw std::runtime_error("Invalid UTF-8 sequence");
    if (conv == std::codecvt_base::ok && bn == be)
      return result;
    // otherwise read another byte and try again
  }
  if (it == end)
    throw std::runtime_error("Incomplete UTF-8 sequence");
  throw std::runtime_error("No character read from first seven bytes");
}
```

This appears to do more work than necessary, re-scanning the whole UTF-8 sequence in `[buf, bufpos)` on every iteration (and making a virtual function call to `codecvt_utf8::do_in`). In theory the `codecvt_utf8::in` implementation could read an incomplete multibyte sequence and store state information in the `mbstate_t` argument, so that the next call would resume from where the last one left off, only consuming new bytes, not re-processing the incomplete multibyte sequence that was already seen.

However, implementations are not *required* to use the `mbstate_t` argument to store state between calls and in practice at least one implementation of `codecvt_utf8::in` (the one I wrote for GCC) doesn't use it at all. From my experiments it seems that the libc++ implementation doesn't use it either. This means that they stop converting before an incomplete multibyte sequence, and leave the `from_next` pointer (the `bn` argument here) pointing to the beginning of that incomplete sequence, so that the next call should start from that position and (hopefully) provide enough additional bytes to complete the sequence and allow a complete Unicode character to be read and converted to `char32_t`. Because you are only trying to read a single codepoint, this means it does no conversion at all, because stopping before an incomplete multibyte sequence means stopping at the first byte.

It's possible that some implementations *do* use the `mbstate_t` argument, so you could modify the function above to handle that case as well, but to be portable it would still need to cope with implementations that ignore the `mbstate_t`. Supporting both types of implementation would complicate the function considerably, so I kept it simple and wrote a form that should work with all implementations, even if they do actually use the `mbstate_t`. Because you are only going to be reading up to 7 bytes at a time (in the worst case ... the average case may be only one or two bytes, depending on the input text) the cost of re-scanning the first few bytes every time shouldn't be huge.

To get better performance from `codecvt_utf8` you should avoid converting one codepoint at a time, because it's designed for converting arrays of characters not individual ones. Since you always need to copy to a `char` buffer anyway you could copy larger chunks from the input iterator sequence and convert whole chunks. This would reduce the likelihood of seeing incomplete multibyte sequences, since only the last 1-3 bytes at the end of a chunk would need to be re-processed if the chunk ends in an incomplete sequence, everything earlier in the chunk would have been converted.

To get better performance reading single codepoints you should probably avoid `codecvt_utf8` entirely and either roll your own (if you only need UTF-8 to UTF-32BE it's not so hard) or use a third-party library such as ICU.

Comment: Yeah, that should work... I don't really like it, but it gives me an idea; I'll experiment a little.

Comment: A bit icky -- O(n^2) in the number of bytes the UTF-32 character consists of there, and n calls to the cvt code.  Given how complex the above is, almost makes sense to roll your own.  (ik)

Comment: No, nevermind. I was hoping I could invoke `codecvt_utf8<char32_t>::in()` one char at a time, keeping the `mbstate_t` inbetween, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: And yes, I agree with Yakk, that's why I said "I don't really like it." (Side note: I had actually already rolled my own and was about to start testing it when it occurred to me that there might be an existing, correct solution in the C++ Standard Library.)

Comment: @Mr.Wonko, the implementation is allowed to use the `mbstate_t` argument to preserve state between calls, but is not required to. In practice it's hard to do so because `mbstate_t` is defined by the underlying C library which most C++ library vendors have no control over. What my implementation of `codecvt_utf8` in GCC does is ignore the state argument and only convert whole codepoints, stopping before an incomplete multibyte sequence. I think the libc++ implementation does the same, based on my experiments.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some additional commentary, in particular noting that you should avoid converting codepoints one by one if you're going to use `codecvt_utf8`